# Can you get notifications from your phone when other devices send data to a joint online database?

Tags: android, database

I am developing an application that sends a notification to your phone when other devices sends data to a joint online database. Anyone know how to do so?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the workflow:

1. Another user adds data to the database
2. this triggers some sort of action
3. this action should result in a push notification

What you have to think of, is how 1. becomes 2. and how 2. becomes 3.

1.->2.: This is a part of the server side application. If it is a database only, you can use triggers to write a row into a notification table. If you have an applications erver, it's much more efficient to let things run there. The easiest (while least feature-rich) version is to increase a "Generation number"

2.->3.: Basically you can chose between the app implementing a background service, and in it poll the server for notifications or use the platforms push notification facility. The former decouples you from the vendor's platforms (which I consider a good thing). Again the easiest version is to just query the generation number and compare it to the last seen one - if it is higher, then somebody entered data and you can notify.